# Need a wiki where I can export to Word

Tags: ms-word, wiki, requirements

I'm looking for a wiki that I can use to track requirements for a project, but we would like to be able to export the wiki (with formatting) to Microsoft Word.  Does anyone know of a wiki that does this?

Answer (score 4):

[Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) does this.  Also exports to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

As tgamblin already mentioned [Confluence](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) does what you want - it'll export to Word.  However it also does more than that; with the (free) [Office Connector](http://www.atlassian.com/office/) you can edit wiki pages in word, edit individual tables in excel, import word documents into the wiki, etc.  Quite nifty if you're looking for that level of integration.

(Fair warning - although they claim it works with OpenOffice, I couldn't get it to work.  Really slick with MS Office though.)

Answer (score 1):

My company is offering an improved Word Exporter for Confluence named "Scroll Office". In contrast to the standard exporter you can export multiple pages and upload a Word document with styles, etc. to define the design of the outputted document. More info: https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/24982

(Disclaimer: I work for the makers of Scroll Office)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free solution, MediaWiki has some [alternative parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers) that might be a good place to look. You might have to go through more than one phase to get it to Microsoft Word format though.